# How does Google determine important links on a website to display in search results?

Tags: google-search, seo

Sometimes when I search for something on Google it shows some results (website links), but it also shows some important links on that website.

Is it a feature of the website or does Google use something to find those main links of the website? Is it related to search engine optimization?

Answer (score 1):

Those are called "Sitelinks" and are automatically determined by Google.

While you cannot tell Google what URLs to use for sitelinks, you can demote URLs that *shouldn't* be used for that purpose. Much more information is available from [Google Support on the topic](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334).

See also: [Official Google Blog: The evolution of sitelinks: expanded and improved](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/08/evolution-of-sitelinks-expanded-and.html)